# Is it possible to create 3D dxf with OGR?

Tags: qgis, open-source-gis, ogr, 3d, dxf

Does anyone know if it's possible to create a 3D dxf with OGR?  I would like to assign the contour lines a Z value and then export them to dxf for some cad work.

PS. I know FME can do this, however I would like to try and find a free solution, and if possible do it in QGIS.

Comment: Autocad map3d does this easily.

Comment: Yeah but Autocad map isn't really free

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Easier then I thought (thanks to BenjaminGolder for the tip):

```
ogr2ogr -f "DXF" Contours.dxf Contours.TAB -zfield Height
```

Contours.TAB is the input MapInfo tab file.

Comment: As far as I can tell this will work for contour lines, but not for true 3d-lines, which have a (x,y,z) coordinate for every point, and not one z value for every point of the line

Comment: I have been trying this in FWTools (2.4.7) without any luck.  Has anyone had any luck?  I am not sure if I am missing something in my GDAL?

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of completeness.

*I believe this should be a comment on Regan response. But since I don't have enough reputation I'll leave it as a response.*

[The DXF writer](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/ogr/ogrsf_frmts/dxf/ogrdxfwriterlayer.cpp?rev=27745) supports 2.5D layers, and given a line input, should output a 3D linestring on dxf.

In the case of input POLYGONS you have to be more careful, since the driver defaults to generate a [dxf HATCH](http://www.autodesk.com/techpubs/autocad/acad2000/dxf/hatch_dxf_06.htm) with a Polyline. And by format specification, that line does not support Z coordinates, only X,Y.

If you input polygons, ogr can export dxf with 3D linestrings representing those polygons. For that you need to set up the config option DXF_WRITE_HATCH to NO.

```
//Bash
export DXF_WRITE_HATCH=NO
ogr2ogr -f "DXF" Contours.dxf Contours.TAB

//Windows
set NEWVAR=SOMETHING
ogr2ogr -f "DXF" Contours.dxf Contours.TAB
```

As far as I am aware this is not documented nor explained anywhere, it was added on revision 24991

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried it, but it should be possible. The [source code for the DXF driver](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/ogr/ogrsf_frmts/dxf/ogrdxfwriterlayer.cpp) writes Z values to dxf if the geometry is 2.5D, which (according to [the source for the shapefile reader](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/ogr/ogrsf_frmts/shape/ogrshapelayer.cpp)) is what you will have if the input shape has Z values.

Comment: That sounds good.  Next question, how do you create a shapefile with Z values.  Say I have a column called Height, is there a easy way to make this the Z value.

Comment: Provided the shapefile is Z-aware, with ArcGIS, you can use a code block in the field calculator.  I don't know how you would do it in Qgis.

Comment: in the ogr2ogr documentation, it appears that you can create a 3d shapefile using the `-zfield` argument and then specifying a field name that holds z values. http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html

Comment: @BenjaminGolder That sounds good.  I will give it a go.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try in GRASS the v.out.dxf command? http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/html64_user/v.out.dxf.html

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, I will give it a go.  I was hoping for a QGIS option also but I could make a script to automate it in GRASS to make it easier to do.