# GRASS v.out.dxf 3D into AutoCAD

Tags: grass-gis, 3d, ogr, autocad, dxf

So continuing with my last question ([Create 3D dxf with OGR](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5843/create-3d-dxf-with-ogr)) I have decided to give the GRASS option a go.

I have imported my polylines into GRASS using v.in.ogr and converted them to 3D using v.to.3d.  I checked the lines using the GRASS info tool and the polylines all have the correct z values.   I then exported it using v.out.dxf but this is where I am having troubles.

The dxf contains the z values for the polylines:

*Extract*

```
VERTEX
8
line
10
401120.708496
20
6875185.007069
 30
539.000000
0
```

However when I open it in AutoCAD Civil 3D it doesn't recognize the z value and just makes all the lines 2D.  I have checked them with the info tool in AutoCAD but the z values are all the same.

Is the dxf created using v.out.dxf supported in AutoCAD in order to get correct 3D?

Comment: you have not provider the 11,21,31 code for that line. Can you provide dxf file so I can get a better look at it?

Comment: Just to be sure, the map is really 3D in GRASS? Confirmed with v.info?

Comment: http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/ticket/1588

Answer (score 1):

What format is your data in?
Civil 3d has map3d as it's base.
Map3d will import most any GIS data.
If you are using civil 3d you should utilize the surface tools in it to import the contours.

Comment: I guess my goal is to be able to send a 3D dxf from our GIS software to consultants.  We only have one copy of Civil 3D and that is used by the design guy pretty much full time.

Comment: and you want to use grass to create. or esri? Sorry but the process is so easy from civil3d I think I would script it and use the design machine at night. or use export to cad from esri.