# How can I use QGIS to convert points with elevations to DXF?

Tags: qgis, autocad, dxf

I'm trying to convert points (with their elevations) into a dxf file for use in AutoCAD LT.  I've tried "save as" to dxf for the layer, which appears to almost work...the dxf has x and y location information, but the elevations associated with the points are not present.

I also tried the "dxfauth" openware tool, but that did the same as the above.  Thanks!

Comment: Where are the elevations stored in your original file? Is it an attribute field?

Comment: Yes, it's an attribute field.  I imported a csv file that contained the survey points with fields: id, x, y, elev, description.

Answer (score 4):

QGIS does not manage Z coordinates importing CSV files.

You can convert the CSV to DXF using `ogr2ogr` from the command-line shell. This should be already installed since QGIS uses OGR too.

You need to create a `.vrt` file along your CSV. This is a plain-text file that you can create with any text editor. It is really easy in your case:

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
  <OGRVRTLayer name="test">
    <SrcDataSource>dave.csv</SrcDataSource>
    <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
    <LayerSRS>WGS84</LayerSRS>
    <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="x" y="y", z="elev"/>
    <Field name="id" type="String"/>
    <Field name="description"/>
  </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

Save this file in the same directory as the CSV file. If the CSV file is called `dave.csv`, it is practical to name it `dave.vrt`. Check on the third line that the `SrcDataSource` is correct, that is that the filename is the same as your CSV file. The `LayerSRS` can probably stay like this, as DXF has no concept of spatial reference system.

When the file is ready, from the command line you would issue:

```
ogr2ogr dave.dxf dave.vrt
```

This procedure is not needed for other formats. See [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5843/create-3d-dxf-with-ogr) about the `zfield` option in `ogr2ogr`.

Comment: Thanks for the great information Steko!  I did as you mentioned, and tried running as described from the windows command prompt (qgis bin directory, where ogr2ogr is located)...it did seem to run, but I got "Failure: unable to open datasource 'pondsur.dxf' with the following drivers..." Thoughts?

Comment: Of course it's not working. I got the order of arguments wrong :( - the destination data source has to be the first one. Fixed in the answer above.